# Как сделать скролл картинок по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css, jquery, css3, html5

Как сделать, что бы картинки располагались как на примере[image: Пример]

И что бы при нажатии на стрелочки картинки проматывались, есть ли готовое решение?
Или нужно делать свой слайдер?

Answer (score 1):

Легче и не придумаешь )

```js
var leftBtn = document.querySelector('#left');
var rightBtn = document.querySelector('#right');

leftBtn.addEventListener('click', slide);
rightBtn.addEventListener('click', slide);

function slide(e) {
  e.target.id === 'left' ? scroll(100) : scroll(-100);
}

function scroll(val) {
  document.querySelector('ul').scrollBy({ 
    left: val,
    behavior: 'smooth' 
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5rem;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 1fr 60px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 100px);
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

li {
  background-color: #c62828;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #212121;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 50%, 100% 100%);
}

#right {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="left"></button>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="right"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Так задумано что клик по стрелки слева скролл идет вправо ?

Comment: Это можно поменять вот тут `scroll(100) : scroll(-100);`

Comment: понятно на мой взгляд надо исправить . P.S. почему не придумаешь ? CTRL + C и CTRL + V

Comment: Я не понимаю о чем ты.

Comment: @ hu-fo-of-ex я свой ответ скопировал отсюда https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#tasks последняя задача :)

Comment: @ hu-fo-of-ex  этому к твоему легче не придумаешь ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Почему не придумаешь CTRL + C и CTRL + V

https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#tasks

```js
 let i = 1;
    for(let li of carousel.querySelectorAll('li')) {
      li.style.position = 'relative';
      li.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0">${i}</span>`);
      i++;
    }

    /* конфигурация */
    let width = 130; // ширина картинки
    let count = 3; // видимое количество изображений

    let list = carousel.querySelector('ul');
    let listElems = carousel.querySelectorAll('li');

    let position = 0; // положение ленты прокрутки

    carousel.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function() {
      // сдвиг влево
      position += width * count;
      // последнее передвижение влево может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент
      position = Math.min(position, 0)
      list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
    };

    carousel.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {
      // сдвиг вправо
      position -= width * count;
      // последнее передвижение вправо может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент
      position = Math.max(position, -width * (listElems.length - count));
      list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
    };
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 398px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  /* делаем этот элемент блочным, чтобы убрать лишнее пространство вокруг картинок */
  display: block;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  left: 7px;
}

.next {
  right: 7px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 390px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery ul {
  height: 130px;
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 250ms;
  /* удаляем пустое пространство между элементами li, у которых установлен inline-block */
  /* http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block */
  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <button class="arrow prev">⇦</button>
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul class="images">
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/6.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/7.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/9.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://ru.js.cx/carousel/10.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Вот прекрасный пример](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/51" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/51/50" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: где картинки ...?

Comment: Картинки надо добавлять в своем проекте :)

Comment: @ Victor  как тогда узнаю работает Ваш код ? :)

Comment: А на то я даю ссылку на этот код :)

Comment: @ Victor  а ссылка в будущем возможно работать не будет ...

Comment: Окей добавил, зануда :)